# Inversion density: Have you seen this concept?

Tags: reference-request, computer-science

Let $n > 1$ be an integer.
Let $A$ be an array, indexed from $1$ to $n$, of $n$ values 
$A(i)$ coming from the finite set $\{0,1\}$.
(More generally, the values can come from any
totally ordered set, but I only need a two element
set for now.)

Let us count the number of inversions in A,
that is the number of pairs $(i,j)$ with
$i < j$ and $A(i) > A(j)$.  Using $[\quad ]$ for Iverson notation, this is

$$I = \sum_{ 1 \le i \le j \le n } [A(i) > A(j)]$$

I call the quantity $I/n^2$ the *inversion density*
of $A$.  As an exercise you can show the inversion density
falls in the closed interval $[0, 1/4]$.

**Question**: Is this (inversion density) or a closely related concept
present in the literature?  If so, please tell me where.

I am still wading through the sorting literature,
where number of inversions in an array are
considered, but I have yet to see anything regarding
a density.  I have not yet found a successful
online search; if a good search term is proffered
I will try it as a substitute for a good reference.

Motivation: I did some research on Combsort and
was looking for worst case complexity results.
After finding some bad (good) cases, I saw that
the same ideas had been more fully developed
in the two papers listed below.  In particular
Poonen has a proposition which can be phrased in
terms of inversion density as: there
is an absolute constant $c$ so that, for any
length $n$, $0$-$1$ array $A$ and for any integer $j$
with $1 < j \le n,$ there is a contiguous length $j$
subarray $B$ (so $B(k) = A(l+k-1)$ for some $l$
 and  $1 \le k \le j$ ) such that the inversion 
density of $B$ is at least $c$ times the inversion
density of $A$.

Poonen shows $c \ge 1/256$.  I
can tighten his argument to show $c \ge 1/32$,
and suspect $c = 1/2$.  I also suspect the 
proposition holds for arrays with values from
any totally ordered set.

References (Please add to this!):

Mark Allen Weiss and Robert Sedgewick,
"Tight Lower Bounds for Shellsort", 
Journal of Algorithms Volume 11, Issue 2, June 1990, Pages 242-251

B. Poonen,  “The worst case in Shellsort and related algorithms,” 
J. of Algorithms 15, 1993, 101-124.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.07.10

Comment: See page 68 of Property testing and parameter testing for permutations by Hoppen et al.  http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2010/SODA10_007_hoppenc.pdf